# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS - PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' - PHP 8.2

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli

I'm struggling with this and just can't find solution. After updating server and all dependencies I'm getting this message on every WordPress page that I have:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
> is required by WordPress.
>
> Please check that the mysqli PHP extension is installed and enabled.
>
> If you are unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact
> your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress
> support forums.

I tried to add `extension=mysqli` in `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.2/apache/php.ini` but nothing worked.

When added in `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` I get this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so:
> undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

Please any suggestions would be appreciated as my websites really need to start working. I searched and try all that I could find but with no luck. Thank you!

Comment: Setting `extension=mysqli` only makes sense when you've to the appropriate shared object library installed. The PHP error message tells you, that you have not.